# SoundCloud: Search & display results using Javascript

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I've created the code below, but it is not working properly.  Where have I gone wrong and or what did I forget to include?

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function results() {
    console.log(search);
 xhr.send() 
}
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results();


// Send the XHR
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search;', true);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- JS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<input type="search" id="search" />
<button onclick="results()">Search</button>
<p id="results"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be helping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest

:Let me know if not

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run on page-load but you want to create an event listener that waits for your user to press Search and then execute your request.

Try:

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var results = xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search;', false);
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
})
```

The 'false' parameter in the xhr request prevents the code from running asynchronously but I am sure you could somehow use callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```js
function audioResults(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
 xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhr.response;
 }, false);
 xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- JS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  
<input type="search" id="search" />
  
<button onclick="audioResults()">Search</button>
  
<p id="results"></p>


</body>
</html>
```